# Oracle: limit block execution time using dbms_scheduler

Tags: oracle, scheduler

I have a great idea but it doesn't work :)

I want to limit pl/sql block execution time and I didn't find ready simple solution.

So I decided to put it in a job and watch its status.

Here's what I got with block as `dbms_lock.sleep(5)` and without time limiting (case when the block has not exceeded the limit)

```
declare 
  sJob varchar2(100) := 'limit_test1';
  bRunning number;
begin
  log('create job');
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(sJob, 'PLSQL_BLOCK', 
    'begin log(''start job''); dbms_lock.sleep(5); log(''finish job''); end;', 
    start_date => systimestamp, enabled => true);
  log('start loop');
  loop
    bRunning := 0;
    for rec in (select 1 from user_scheduler_running_jobs t where t.job_name = sJob) loop
      bRunning := 1;
    end loop;
    log('bRunning = '||bRunning);
    exit when bRunning = 0; -- **or time limit routine**
    dbms_lock.sleep(1);
  end loop;
end;
```

I expect log like

```
create job
start job
start loop
bRunning = 1
bRunning = 1
bRunning = 1
finish job
bRunning = 0
```

but i get

```
create job
start loop
bRunning = 0
start job
finish job
```

maybe I need to use another dictionary view or `sleep` somewhere

Comment: Job execution will be asynchronous to your PL/SQL block and will not begin until the block is complete and closed. Your check loop needs to be in a separate PL/SQL block.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: How is this code related to the question's title?

Comment: I want to wait for the result of some pl/sql block no more than, say, 10 seconds and continue program in any case. Are you sure job will not begin until the outer block is complete?

Comment: I removed the code that counts down 10 seconds for simplicity and I want to debug the case when the block in the job is executed in less time

Comment: It is still not clear what you are trying to achieve. If the code should run regardless of the job status, then just run. If you want to get job status, then obtain it via scheduler API. Trying to wait for any time for asynchronous thing defeats it's asynchronous nature: scheduler may be busy for arbitrary time frame, asynchronous task may only guarantee that it will finish *at some time*. That's why we use callbacks for asynchronous processing

Comment: Callbacks aren't an easily usable option in procedural PL/SQL programming. I can think of a few use cases for something like this: (1) traffic control (submit jobs one after another but if they take too long move on prematurely), (2) possibly hanging actions (do some network call that might hang forever, if it takes too long kill it and move on), (3) parallel child job control (create child jobs to parallelize work and wait for all the children to finish because you need the aggregate data from all of them to move forward), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jobs don't start instantly. The job controller has to poll and find runnable jobs and then starts them up. This can take several seconds.  You are on the right path, you simply need to use `user_scheduler_jobs` instead of `user_scheduler_running_jobs`. Be sure that your job is configured to auto-drop (that may be the default without an interval defined, but it's better to explicitly add `auto_drop => TRUE` to the parameters).

The job will show in the view instantly upon creation, so there's no need to wait before starting to poll. As soon as the job is completed, it will disappear from the view.